# Submitting a form doesn't work as it should

Tags: php, forms, submit

I've been trying to do the simplest thing, creating a login page on my server, but for some reason it just does not work. I'v checked my code over and over again but can't find the solution. Guessing it's something fairly simple but I'm getting blind to my own code. :(  I have a register.php site that works, just the logging in part (on index.php) that doesn't work. :(  The code doesn't even seem to regiser that I've pushed 'submit' and just goes into my

```
   if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
```

I'm working in PHP and HTML5. Here is my code as follows (sorry, it's long but only in one file ... and also sorry, some Icelandic comments in there ;) ):

```
<div id="content">
<?php 
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    echo " ! isset( $ _POST [ ' submit ' ] ";

    if(!isset($_SESSION['logged']))
    {
        echo " ! isset ( $ _SESSION [ ' logged ' ] ";
    ?>
        <h1>Umsjónarsvæði - innskráning</h1>

        <form action='' method='post'>
            <div class='form_line'>
                <div class='form_left_side'>Notandanafn:</div>
                <div class='form_right_side'><input type='Text' name='user'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='form_line'>
                <div class='form_left_side'>Lykilorð:</div>
                <div class='form_right_side'><input type='Password' name='pass'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='clear'><hr /></div>
            <div class='form_button'><input class='buttons' type="submit" name="submit" value='Skrá' />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class='buttons' type='reset' value='Hreinsa' /></div>
        </form>
    <?php
    }
    else 
    {
        echo " isset ( $ _SESSION [ ' logged ' ] ";
    ?>
        <h1>Umsjónarsvæði</h1>
        <p>Á umsjónarsvæðinu er hægt að skoða mótteknar fyrirspurnir, virkar eignavaktir og nýskrá og sýsla með eignir á forsíðu.</p>
        <p>Notið valmyndina hér til hliðar til að flakka um síðuna.</p>
    <?php
    }
}
else {
    session_destroy();
    $skuli = new SQL();

    $user = $skuli->isSafe($_POST['user']);
    $pa = $skuli->isSafe($_POST['pass']);

    $db_users = $skuli->getUsers($user, $pa);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($db_users);
    if($count > 0)
    {
                $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['logged'] = 1;
        // og stillum það að session "lifi" í 5 tíma
        ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", "18000");
        echo "isLogged: ".$_SESSION['logged']."<br/>";
        //session_write_close(); 
        // förum loks aftur á þessa aðal síðu ...
        header('Location: index.php'); 
        exit(); 
    }
    else 
    {
        $count = $skuli->checkUser($user);
        echo "<h1>Umsjónarsvæði - innskráning - $count</h1>";

        if($count < 1)
        {
            echo "<p>Notandinn <i>$user</i> finnst ekki á skrá. Vinsamlegast reynið aftur.</p><br/>";

        }
        else {
            echo "<p>Notandinn <i>$user</i> með þessu lykilorði finnst ekki á skrá. Vinsamlegast reynið aftur.</p><br/>";
        }
        ?>

        <form action='' method='post'>
            <div class='form_line'>
                <div class='form_left_side'>Notandanafn:</div>
                <div class='form_right_side'><input type='Text' name='user'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='form_line'>
                <div class='form_left_side'>Lykilorð:</div>
                <div class='form_right_side'><input type='Password' name='pass'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='clear'><hr /></div>
            <div class='form_button'><input class='buttons' type='submit' name='submit' value='Skrá' />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class='buttons' type='reset' value='Hreinsa' /></div>
        </form>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, I'm lost in this (been looking to long, just can't see what I'm missing). :(

Thanks

No comments? Am still lost :(

Comment: *"my `if (!isset($_POST['submit']))` -loop"* -- An `if` statement is not a loop.

Comment: `print_r($_POST);`  see the issue?

Comment: Sorry Jonathon Reinhart, I know if isn't a loop, some language-issues (plus lack of sleep). :)

Comment: @Dagon, this just prints out an empty array. I'm lost :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the action of the form, for example:

```
<form action='<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post'>
```

P.S. in the HTML is better to write `<hr>` or `<br>` and not `<hr />` or `<br />` but is only for a non-warning, the code is however correct.

Comment: @Loreti, this doesn't change anything. I had tried PHP_SELF but no luck.